# Numeric or valuer errors when passing decimals as SQL function params

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

In a SQL function defined as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION num_has_changed(new_val in NUMBER, old_val in NUMBER)
RETURN BOOLEAN AS
    has_changed  BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
   has_changed := (old_val IS NULL AND new_val IS NOT NULL) OR (new_val <> old_val);
   RETURN has_changed;
END num_has_changed;
```

It runs successfully when executed as `num_has_changed(10,5)` but throws an error when the passed values are decimals as in `num_has_changed(10.2,5.5)`

The error thrown is

```
06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"
*Cause:    An arithmetic, numeric, string, conversion, or constraint error
           occurred. For example, this error occurs if an attempt is made to
           assign the value NULL to a variable declared NOT NULL, or if an
           attempt is made to assign an integer larger than 99 to a variable
           declared NUMBER(2).
*Action:   Change the data, how it is manipulated, or how it is declared so
           that values do not violate constraints.
```

EDIT: For testing purposes I am calling it in the simplest way possible and still getting the error:

```
BEGIN
    IF num_has_changed(10.1,5.1) then
        UPDATE 
           ACTIONS 
        SET 
          PAID = 1 
        WHERE 
          ID = 1
    END IF;
END;
```

As a note, the update alone works properly.

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: I am not sure, but did you try putting your conditions into IF-ELSE logic and try ?

Comment: Which line is the error reported against? The context of the call might be useful. Maybe you're actually passing variables, and the error is when values are assigned to those, for instance?

Comment: I edited the question with the call context.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this error with yur example. Try to add an Exception   inside your function this line may show you where the Exception happen dbms_output.put_line(DBMS_UTILITY.format_error_backtrace);

Comment: Me neither; works just fine on my 11.2.0.4.0.

Comment: Weirdly, it seems to work just fine when being called from a trigger, even when passing decimal numbers, Will look into this closely when I have some more time. By now consider it solved. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Just a guess but what is your NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS set to be ?